# How to read data from sequence files using Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have the sequence file with key as text and value as custom data type.

But Spark streaming is unable to read data from the sequence file.

```
JavaPairInputDStream<Text, CustomDataType> myRDD =
        jssc.fileStream(path, Text.class, CustomDataType.class, SequenceFileInputFormat.class,
            new Function<Path, Boolean>() {
          @Override
          public Boolean call(Path v1) throws Exception {
            return Boolean.TRUE;
          }
        }, false);
```

Following is the syntax error from IDE.

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method fileStream(String, Class<K>, Class<V>, Class<F>, Function<Path,Boolean>, boolean) of type JavaStreamingContext is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class<Text>, Class<DeltaCounter>, Class<SequenceFileInputFormat>, new Function<Path,Boolean>(){}, boolean). The inferred type SequenceFileInputFormat is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <F extends InputFormat<K,V>>
```

How to read sequence file in Spark streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a correct package in imports. You are probably importing the old `org.apache.hadoop.mapred`. Use this code:

```java
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat;
```